# Using Boost with Windows 10 universal app

Tags: c++, boost, windows-10, win-universal-app

I`m developing Windows 10 universal app, mainly targeting Windows phones. When trying to use boost I get errors like this:

```
boost/asio/detail/impl/win_thread.ipp(48): error C2039: 'TerminateThread': is not a member of '`global namespace''
```

As far as I understand, this problem occurs due to boost using win32 api which is not supported in Windows 10 universal application. I tried both 1.58 ( current official release) and 1.59 (release candidate). Are there any flags I`m missing? Do you have any information related to boost and Windows universal app support?

---

I`ve created minimal program to reproduce this error:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

In fact the first error I get is:

```
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um\processthreadsapi.h(491): error C3861: 'FlsAlloc': identifier not found
```

Comment: report as a bug and if you don't need asio exclude it from the build.

Comment: `FlsAlloc` is allowed for Store apps, but `TerminateThread` is not; it is [very dangerous](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx). Do you need any special flags to build Boost with Store compatibility? (Sorry I don't know Boost).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all Boost libraries can be used for Windows Universal Apps. Work to make more of them be usable with Universal apps is ongoing. Here's more information: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/07/18/using-boost-libraries-in-windows-store-and-phone-applications/

Post author, Steven Gates, has comments indicating that Boost.Asio is likely using banned APIs. I'm not able to link to individual comments, so partially quoting here (emphasis mine):

> Steven Gates
>   @Li Ning 82: Boost.ASIO depends on the WinSock API, which just recently is now allowed on Windows Phone 8. However I'd bet that **ASIO is using other APIs that are banned**, that you'd have to replace.

Also, CreateThread, CreateThreadPool, etc are not available in Windows Universal apps.

Having said the above, I'm going to assume that you'll have to use something other than Boost.Asio, in which here's some additional info that may help:

The recommended way to simulate multithreading is the use of [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194921(v=vs.110).aspx). You can also use [TaskFactory.StartNew](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx).

For completion, here's the list of [Win32 & COM APIs for Windows Runtime apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn424765.aspx). and [Alternatives to Windows APIs in Windows Runtime apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464945.aspx).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Marcin is asking about C++, however, you are suggesting to use `Task.Run` and `TaskFactory.StartNew` which is not available in C++.

Comment: @YuchenZhong - that's not entirely correct. When using C++ to create UWP, you'll have to use MS extensions to C++ that allow you to call in to the .NET libraries. See this example on the Task.Run page in C++:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194921(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp